# Мультиязычность с javascript на всех страницах сайта

Tags: javascript, cookie

Есть небольшой скрипт для организации мультиязычности на сайте, с переключениям на кнопках:

```js
    var en = {
      'home': 'Home',
      'about': 'About Us',
      'contact': 'Contact Us'
    };
    var ua = {
      'home': 'Головна',
      'about': 'Про нас',
      'contact': 'Контакти'
    };

    function changeLang(lan) {
      lengthObj = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(lan).length;
      for (var i = 0; i <= lengthObj - 1; i++) {
        objKey = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(lan)[i];
        document.getElementById(objKey).innerText = func(objKey);
      }

      function func(a) {
        for (key in lan) {
          if (key == a) {
            return (lan[key]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="/first">first</a>
  <a href="/second">second</a>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/header.js"></script>

  <button class="translate" id="en" onclick="
    changeLang(en);
    ">English</button>
  <button class="translate" id="ua" onclick="
    changeLang(ua);
    ">Українська</button>

  <p class="lang">
    <p id="home">Home</p>
  </p>
  <p class="lang">
    <p id="about">About Us</p>
  </p>
  <p class="lang">
    <p id="contact">Contact s</p>
  </p>
</header>
```

Он работает хорошо, но при переходе на следующую страницу, например, контакты (и т.д.), выбранный язык не сохраняется.

Перечитал литературу и понял, что надо как-то с куками или сессиями работать, но ничего толкового не нашёл. Помогите или покажите качественную литературу. В вебе новичок.

Comment: Прочитай аномально мой ответ там все есть

Comment: @СеменихинМаксим ваша правка сломала код в вопросе и я её откатил. В этом можно было убедиться, тупо нажав "Выполнить код" и потыкав на кнопки.  `changeLang` принимает **объект**, а не строку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ориентироваться на [современные браузеры](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage), можно в [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) сохранять выбранный язык:

```
lang = 'ru';                        // пользователь выбрал язык
localStorage.setItem('lang', lang); // сохранили в LS
```

На всех страницах получение выбранного сохранённого языка:

```
var lang = localStorage.getItem('lang') || 'en'; // язык по умолчанию
```

---

Примерно так:

```js
var txt = {
  en: {'home':'Home', 'about':'About Us', 'contact':'Contact Us'}
  ,ua: {'home':'Головна','about':'Про нас','contact':'Контакти'}
};
document.getElementById('e-lang-en').addEventListener('click', setLang.bind(null,'en'));
document.getElementById('e-lang-ua').addEventListener('click', setLang.bind(null,'ua'));

function setLang(lang){
  var p;
  if( !txt.hasOwnProperty(lang)) return;
  if( window.hasOwnProperty('localStorage'))
     window.localStorage.setItem('lang', lang);
  for(p in txt[lang]) {
    document.getElementById(p).innerText = txt[lang][p];
  }
}

var lang = (window.hasOwnProperty('localStorage') && window.localStorage.getItem('lang', lang)) || 'en';
setLang(lang);
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="/first">first</a>
  <a href="/second">second</a>

  <button class="translate" id="e-lang-en">English</button>
  <button class="translate" id="e-lang-ua">Українська</button>

  <p class="lang">
    <p id="home">Home</p>
  </p>
  <p class="lang">
    <p id="about">About Us</p>
  </p>
  <p class="lang">
    <p id="contact">Contacts</p>
  </p>
</header>
```

В этой песочнице LS заблокирован. [Рабочий пример](https://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/5h4ytenv/) на JSFiddle. По умолчанию английский язык. Поставьте украинский и перезапустите фиддл – сразу будет `ua`.

Comment: Интересная идея. Но , к сожелению, моих знаний, недостаточно, что б реализовать ее у себя. Не будет ли слишком нахально попросить вас осуществить такое к моей функции?

Comment: Попробуйте сами, покажите, что сделали и что не получается.

Comment: Upd. добавил рабочий пример

Comment: Спасибо огромное.Вы спасли мою нервную сисему

Comment: Блин, возникла еще одна проблема. Если же блок будет находиться на некоторой странице(например second), то на нем язык не смениться. Возможно ли это пофиксить?Добавить мб что-то?

Comment: весь приведённый код должен быть на всех страницах

Comment: я подключаю часть header вот таким способом <%- include ../parts/header.ejs %> , что значит, что он на всех страницах присутсвует.

Comment: JavaScript тоже нужен на каждой, причем, желательно, в самом конце, перед закрывающими `</body></html>`

Comment: Оу. Спасибо вам огромнейшее!

Answer (score 2):

Вариантов не много.

**или использовать localStorage**

- localStorage.setItem('lan', lan);
- lang = localStorage.getItem('lann');

**или предавать через Get параметр**

- [How to retrieve GET parameters from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript)
- [Adding a parameter to the URL with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript)

**или через cookie**

```
function setCookie(name, value, options) {
  options = options || {};

  var expires = options.expires;

  if (typeof expires == "number" && expires) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + expires * 1000);
    expires = options.expires = d;
  }
  if (expires && expires.toUTCString) {
    options.expires = expires.toUTCString();
  }

  value = encodeURIComponent(value);

  var updatedCookie = name + "=" + value;

  for (var propName in options) {
    updatedCookie += "; " + propName;
    var propValue = options[propName];
    if (propValue !== true) {
      updatedCookie += "=" + propValue;
    }
  }

  document.cookie = updatedCookie;
}



function getCookie(name) {
  var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
    "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
  ));
  return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}
```

Так или иначе тебе нужно будет при загрузки стрицы

```
<script>
  function ready() {
    alert( 'DOM готов' );

// changeLang(); 
// в итоге это должно быть раскоменчено
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
</script>
```

вызвать твою функцию что бы она загрузила нужный язык

Твою же функцию можно изменить так

```
function changeLang(lan){
    if('undefined'=== typeof lan )
       lan = getCookie('lan') || 'en';
    else
        setCookie('lan', lan);
//        if(!lan)
//            lan  ='en';

    lengthObj = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(lan).length;
    for (var i = 0; i <= lengthObj-1; i++) {
        objKey = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(lan)[i];
        document.getElementById(objKey).innerText=func(objKey);
    }
    function func(a){
        for(key in lan) {
            if (key == a) {
                return(lan[key]);}
        }
    }
}
```

если вызвать её без передачи языка он будет считан из куку

Comment: возможно я туплю, так как с js работаю всего 3 недели, но если заменить вашу функцию на мою, она не работает. Нужно мне еще что нибудь прописывать, или только изменить функцию?

Comment: Не работает наверно так как там есть вызовы функций для работы с куками, ест ты их не копировал то конечно не будет работать

Comment: Да точно. Функция работает. Но проблема все та же. При переходе на след страницу все меняеться обратн.

Comment: При любом действии програма записывает в куки значения  lengthObj=ua; и lan=%5Bobject%20Object%5D. И почему то не работает(

Comment: выложи код что у тебя получается на https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: внезапно появился вариант с LS! : )   Подсказка: ещё можно через хэш-параметр передавать язык: `site.ru/first#ru`.   ..И вот это бесценно, конечно:  `alert( 'DOM готов' );` – без этого сайт не заработает )

Comment: да, его добавил.  с хешами пожалуй оставля вам =)

Answer (score 0):

Есть отличное решение jQuery плагин [D2S:Lang](https://lang.dev2studio.com)
Переводит на лету

Comment: А как им пользоваться, не покажите? Ответы состоящие из одной ссылки обычно удаляются.